# как сделать такой же график на html и css

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как и с помощью чего можно сделать. заранее благодарен

Answer (score 3):

Есть такой интересный элемент [meter](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)

```css
meter:before{
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<meter low=".25" optimum=".15" high=".75" value="0.1" title="Time"></meter><br>
<meter low=".25" optimum=".15" high=".75" value="0.5" title="Price"></meter><br>
<meter low=".25" optimum=".15" high=".75" value="0.9" title="Quality"></meter><br>
```

Comment: хороший способ, но, к сожалению, IE не одобряет) +

Comment: @meine я не сомневался, но осуждать его не буду

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример:

```css
.item {
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.percent {
  width: 78%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="percent">
    Характеристика
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на тот случай когда текст должен читаться одновременно на обоих фонах:

```css
.item, .progress {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:navy;
  background-color:#F1F3F4;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  padding:0px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px navy inset;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.progress {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
}

span {padding-left:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <span>Photoshop 15%</span>
  <div class="progress" style="width:15%"><span>Photoshop 15%</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span>Corel Draw 100%</span>
  <div class="progress" style="width:100%"><span>Corel Draw 100%</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span>Inkscape 0%</span>
  <div class="progress" style="width:0%"><span>Inkscape 0%</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span>Paint 78%</span>
  <div class="progress" style="width:78%"><span>Paint 78%</span></div>
</div>
```