# Цвет полоски меняется за счет числа выше

Tags: html, css

Как сделать полоску, которая будет меняться при изменении цифры выше?
Желательно на html+css.
Если вопрос глупый - не бейте, неделю в верстке.
Скрины -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Здесь как вариант вам нужен js. Как сделать ? изучать js... [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/) или [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn). Html+css это просто внешний вид, а менять внешний вид в зависимости от числа  (которое тоже кстати меняется программно, можно не только js, но js чаще всего в браузерах применяется для таких дел) это только программно.

Comment: @noname2019 это то понятно, но мне нужно доделать эту работу и скорее мне не нужен полный js, а просто этот код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1030775/188366

Answer (score 2):

**1.**

```js
var elPlayersOnline = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__players-info__online');
var elPlayersLimit = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__players-info__limit');
var elLineDone = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__line__done');

var valPlayersOnline = elPlayersOnline.innerText;
var valPlayersLimit = elPlayersLimit.innerText;

//вместо инпута может быть что угодно, что меняет текстовые узлы
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', changeOnline);

// инициализация
changeWidth(valPlayersOnline, valPlayersLimit);
input.value = valPlayersOnline;


function changeWidth(online, limit) {
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(online)) && Number.isInteger(parseInt(limit)))
    elLineDone.style.width = `${online * (100 / limit)}%`;
  else
    elLineDone.style.width = '70%';
}

function changeOnline(e) {
  elPlayersOnline.innerText = e.target.value;
}

// следим за именениями внутри progress-bar__players-info__online
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  changeWidth(mutationsList[0].target.innerText, valPlayersLimit);
};

const config = {
  childList: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(elPlayersOnline, config);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.progress-bar__players-info {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.progress-bar__players-info__online {}

.progress-bar__players-info__limit {}

.progress-bar__line {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar__line__done {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar__players-info">
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__online">23</span>
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__separator">/</span>
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__limit">30</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar__line">
    <div class="progress-bar__line__done"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="30">
```

**2.**

```js
var elPlayersOnline = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__players-info__online');
var elPlayersLimit = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__players-info__limit');
var elLineDone = document.querySelector('.progress-bar__line__done');

var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = elPlayersOnline.innerText;
changeWidth(elPlayersOnline.innerText, elPlayersLimit.innerText)

input.addEventListener('input', changeOnline);

function changeWidth(online, limit) {
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(online)) && Number.isInteger(parseInt(limit)))
    elLineDone.style.width = `${online * (100 / limit)}%`;
  else
    elLineDone.style.width = '70%';
}

function changeOnline(e) {
  elPlayersOnline.innerText = e.target.value;
  changeWidth(elPlayersOnline.innerText, elPlayersLimit.innerText)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.progress-bar__players-info {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.progress-bar__players-info__online {}

.progress-bar__players-info__limit {}

.progress-bar__line {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar__line__done {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar__players-info">
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__online">23</span>
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__separator">/</span>
    <span class="progress-bar__players-info__limit">30</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar__line">
    <div class="progress-bar__line__done"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" max="30">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое всем! Очень помогли

Comment: А не проще ли вызывать изменение ширины просто в той функции, которая меняет число ?)

Comment: Да. Я просто одно делал , об другом думал и третье получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на `jQuery`

```js
// входящие данные
let thisPlayers = 17,
    maxPlayers = 30;
    
// Сделаем через функцию, ибо если понадобится обновлять статистику, то через неё будет проще.
function ProgressOnlinePlayers(play,max){
  let progress = Math.floor(play/max*100); // тут мы получим процент, который дальше будем использовать в прогресс-баре.
  // p.s. функцию Math.floor поможет округлить полученое число.
  
  $('.text') // обратимся к блоку text
    .text(play+'/'+max); // и выведем туда данные
  
  $('.progress .bg') // далее обратимся к фону прогресс-бара
    .css('width', progress+'%'); // и зададим ему ширину в процентах
}

ProgressOnlinePlayers(thisPlayers, maxPlayers); // вызываем функцию с нашими входными данными
```

```css
.progress {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress .bg {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text"></div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

---

Тоже самое, только с демо-примером как у [@hu-fo-of-ex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049728/221218)

```js
let thisPlayers = 17,
    maxPlayers = 30;
    
function ProgressOnlinePlayers(play,max){
  let progress = Math.floor(play/max*100); 
  $('.text').text(play+'/'+max);
  $('.progress .bg').css('width', progress+'%');
}
ProgressOnlinePlayers(thisPlayers,maxPlayers);

$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function(){
  let val = $(this).val();
  ProgressOnlinePlayers(val,maxPlayers);
});
```

```css
.progress {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress .bg {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text"></div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
<br>
<input type="range" min="0" value="17" max="30">
```